# Comparing and sorting parametrized types in a list?

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I am experimenting with a simple program that creates a bank account and has transactions tied to it. It works flawlessly when I am using primitive types, however I included a possibility of adding a String operation (such as ERROR when withdrawing), and now I am not sure how can I sort the list so that the String operations don't appear at all when printed out, if filtered, or appear at the bottom if sorted.

Full source code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BankAccount bankAccount = new BankAccount();
    bankAccount.addTransaction(2, TransactionType.DEPOSIT);
    bankAccount.addTransaction(100.66, TransactionType.DEPOSIT);
    bankAccount.addTransaction(2, TransactionType.WITHDRAW);
    bankAccount.addTransaction("ERROR", TransactionType.WITHDRAW);

    List<Transaction> transactions = bankAccount.getTransactions();

    List<Transaction> collect = transactions.stream()
            //Error appears over here, probably due to wrong syntax of the two next lines.
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing((Transaction tr) -> tr.getAmount()).reversed()) 
            .filter(tr -> tr.getAmount() > 0)
            .collect(toList());
    collect.forEach(tr -> System.out.println(tr));
}

private static class BankAccount {
    private List<Transaction> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    public <T> void addTransaction(T amount, TransactionType transactionType) {
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(amount, transactionType);
        transactions.add(transaction);
        //return 0;
    }

    public List<Transaction> getTransactions() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(transactions);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BankAccount{" +
                "transactions=" + transactions +
                '}';
    }
}

private static class Transaction<T> {
    private final T amount;
    private final TransactionType transactionType;
    private final Date dateCreated;

    public Transaction(T amount, TransactionType transactionType) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    public T getAmount() {
        return amount;

    }

    public TransactionType getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Transaction{" +
                "amount=" + amount +
                ", transactionType=" + transactionType +
                ", dateCreated=" + dateCreated +
                '}';
    }
}

private static enum TransactionType {
    DEPOSIT, WITHDRAW;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is you are comparing apples to oranges when you mix `Transaction<Double>` with `Transaction<String>`.  Your `BankAccount` can only hold one type of `Transaction`.  They are either all `Transaction<Double>` or `Transaction<String>`.

Right now because you do not have your `BankAccount` class parameterized it is treating it like `Transaction<Object>`.

The solution is to properly parameterize the `BankAccount` and code accordingly.  Here is a version coded up using `BankAccount<String>`.

**NOTE:** The example is relying on `String` comparison of numbers which is not a sound strategy.  I moved the `filter()` call up to remove the "ERROR" transactions first.  Then you will want to consider parsing back to numbers in the function you pass to `comparing()`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    BankAccount<String> bankAccount = new BankAccount<>();
    bankAccount.addTransaction(Double.toString(2.00), TransactionType.DEPOSIT);
    bankAccount.addTransaction(Double.toString(100.66), TransactionType.DEPOSIT);
    bankAccount.addTransaction(Double.toString(2.00), TransactionType.WITHDRAW);
    bankAccount.addTransaction("ERROR", TransactionType.WITHDRAW);

    List<Transaction<String>> transactions = bankAccount.getTransactions();

    List<Transaction<String>> collect = transactions.stream()
            .filter(tr -> !tr.getAmount().equals("ERROR"))
            .sorted(Comparator.<Transaction<String>, String> comparing(transaction -> transaction.getAmount()).reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    collect.forEach(tr -> System.out.println(tr.getAmount() + " " + tr.getType().name()));
}

public static class BankAccount<T> {

    private List<Transaction<T>> transactions = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTransaction(T amount, TransactionType transactionType) {
        Transaction<T> transaction = new Transaction <>(amount, transactionType);
        transactions.add(transaction);
    }

    public List<Transaction<T>> getTransactions() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(transactions);
    }
}

public static class Transaction<T> {
    private final T amount;
    private final TransactionType transactionType;
    private final Date dateCreated;

    public Transaction(T amount, TransactionType transactionType) {
        this.amount = amount;
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
        this.dateCreated = new Date();
    }

    public T getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public TransactionType getType(){
        return transactionType;
    }

    public Date getDateCreated(){
        return dateCreated;
    }

}

public enum TransactionType {
    DEPOSIT, WITHDRAW;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare (sort) objects with different type why don't you for example write own Comparator for it?

Example:

```
List<Transaction> collect = transactions.stream()
    .sorted((t1, t2) -> {
        if (t1.getAmount() instanceof String && t2.getAmount() instanceof String) {
            return String.class.cast(t1.getAmount()).compareTo(String.class.cast(t2.getAmount()));
        } else if (t1.getAmount() instanceof String) {
            return 1;
        } else if (t2.getAmount() instanceof String) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return new BigDecimal(t1.getAmount().toString()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(t2.getAmount().toString())); //ugly hack
        }
    })
    .filter(tr -> tr.getAmount() instanceof Number && Number.class.cast(tr.getAmount()).doubleValue() > 0) //next ugly hack
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
collect.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thought about it, but I also thought there is already existing way to compare and/or sort different types. Thanks for the example nonetheless!